Решаю задачу с codeforces на dp, выдает runtime error
https://codeforces.com/group/LB1sSRhotq/contest/268096/attachments, задача - лестница.
Дан n, и список длиной n.
Мы идем по списку с шагом 1, либо 2 и суммируем числа, в которые попали; надо максимизировать эту сумму.
n = int(input()) 
a = list(map(int, input().split())) 
 
dp = [-1] * (n+2) 
def f(n): 
    if dp[n] != -1: 
        return dp[n] 
    if n == 1: 
        dp[n] = a[0] 
    elif n == 2: 
        dp[n] = max(a[1], a[0]+a[1]) 
    else: 
        dp[n] = max(f(n-1) + a[n-1], f(n-2) + a[n-1]) 
    return dp[n] 
print(f(n))

Вот код, который выдает на 1 тест - 3 (1, [1, 2] -> 3), однако при выполнении кода пишет runtime error, хотя бесконечной рекурсии здесь не может быть, да и глубина рекурсии не более 100, так что я хочу узнать, в чем здесь ошибка.

Прямую ссылку на задание сложно приложить? Или тестируете нас, найдем не найдем вашу лестницу? Вы сам код дебажить пробовали? Уверены, что ваш dp и a виден внутри функции? Код хоть раз правильно выдал ответ?

Да, уверен, а самой задачи нет в виде страницы на cf, есть только файл, ссылку я приложил

На все тесты, которые я придумал, выдает правильный ответ: -4 5 -1 7 -> 12; 1, -3, 4 -> 5; и еще 1 тест, на 1000 положительных элементов, которые сгенерировал рандомом

Выглядит правильно. Можно решить восходящим ДП без рекурсии, но разницы быть не должно

Пустой список (из нуля элементов) не может быть на входе?

нет, n от 1 до 10**5

А как вы поняли, что рекурсия не глубже 100? Я задал 10000 случайных элементов и получил ошибку "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison". Питон очень не любит рекурсию глубиной больше 1000, ну, вернее, зависит от версии интерпретатора и частично это настраивается, но в любом случае лучше на это не закладываться и глубокой рекурсии избегать. Я посмотрел, у меня пробило лимит 3000. Можно выставить на 20000 с риском краша интерпретатора, но вряд ли вроде больше.

@MBo Похоже, дело таки в рекурсии, лимит её превышается.

@CrazyElf Тут в комментариях выясняется, что n до 100000, в пдф-ке всего 100

А ларчик просто открывался. Решения со стандартным входом/выходом не принимаются. Вы обязаны читать задание из файла ladder.in и записывать ответ в файл ladder.out.
Добавлю что задача может быть решена без рекурсии и без массива. Для вычисления максимума следующей ступеньки достаточно знать максимумы двух предыдущих (переменные sp, s):
with open('ladder.in') as f:
    next(f) 
    sp, s = 0, 0
    for ai in map(int, next(f).split()):
        sp, s = s, max(sp, s) + ai

with open('ladder.out', 'w') as f:
    print(s, file=f)

P.S. Задача безобразно поставлена. Наврано в условии, условия приёма отличаются от общепринятых. Немудрено запутаться.

Восходящее динамическое программирование не требует рекурсии:
dp = [0] * (n+1)
dp[1] = a[0]
for i in range(2,n+1):
    dp[i] = max(dp[i-1], dp[i-2]) + a[i-1]
print(dp[n])

(на Python можно даже убрать вторую строчку и цикл с единицы запустить, т.к. обращение к -1 элементу ничего не испортит)
